# How to handle Laravel NotFoundHttpException?

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes

I am learning Laravel by doing a self-exercise. Basically what I want to achieve is the parameter ‘id’ can be passed to the Controller from Route to get a list of different topics for that specific id when the link is clicked. I have checked all other posts and seems I can't get the answer there.

Here is my code in Route.php where mainpage is the index page of my application.

```
Route::get('/public/', array( 'as' => 'Personal_assistant' , 'uses' => 'category_by_user@get_mainpage'));
Route::get('public/{id}' , array( 'as' => 'viewtopic' , 'uses' => 'category_by_user@get_topic'));
```

My code in Controller 'category_by_user':

```
class Category_by_user extends Controller
{ 
//

public $restful = true;

public function get_mainpage()
{

 $data = DB::table('categories')
      -> select('category_name', 'category_description')
    //->where('category_user_id', '=' , $user_id)
     ->get(); 

  return view::make('mainpage')
       ->with('title', 'Category By User')
        ->with('data' , $data );
  }


  public function get_topic($id)
  {
       $data1 = DB::table('topics')
       ->where('Category_id', '=' , $id)
      ->get(); 


      return View::make('viewtopic') 
         ->with('title', 'All Topic by Category')
         ->with('data1' , $data1)
         ->with('id' , $id);
       }
 }
```

My code in viewtopic.blade.php:

```
 {h1>Personal Info Assistant</h1>

  <!-- will be used to show any messages -->
  @if (Session::has('message'))
        <div class="alert alert-info">{{ Session::get('message') }}</div>
  @endif

  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">

   <tbody>
   <!--  // List all categories belongs to that particular user -->


   @foreach($data1 as $key => $topic)
       <tr>

        <td>{{ $topic->topic_description }}</td>
        <td>ID = {{ $id }}</td>

      </tr>
   @endforeach
   </tbody>
 </table>

 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Error detail log as follows:

```
    in RouteCollection.php line 161
    at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 821
    at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 691
    at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
    at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
    at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php     line 52
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Debugbar.php line 49
    at Debugbar->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(Debugbar), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
    at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
    at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
    at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
    at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
    at require_once('C:\wamp\www\Personal_Info_App\public\index.php') in server.php line 21
```

Thanks so much in advanced for any help out there.

Comment: As far I can see there is something wrong with you defined routes. Try (to be sure) `/public` instead of `/public/` and `/public/{id}` instead of `public/{id}`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the links and the code that passes in your links the id? Maybe the $id is not passed correctly in your href attr.

Comment: I don't think the `id` is the problem since it is a `NotFoundHttpException`. But it would be very helpfull for us to see the url he requested.

Comment: Thanks for all the quick responses out there. I have attached 2 images with the link of mainpage ( 1st one ) and the link after I clicked on one  of the categories. Hope I supply the right info. thanks again.